# Swift 2.2 - How to create two and more sections under specific segment (of UISegmentedControl)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm building my first iOS app and I would like to create following:

- UISegmentedControl that has about 4 segments (e.g. All, Movies, TV, Music)
- when e.g. Movies is selected, UITableView should show predefined sections (e.g. Pulp Fiction, 12 Angry Men, Fight Club, The Dark Knight)
- every section will contain (also predefined) cells (e.g. under Pulp Fiction there will be cells: John Travolta, Quentin Tarantino, Uma Thurman, Samuel L. Jackson)
- also, I would like to have a segment All with all sections and cells

I was able to create UITableView where e.g. segment Movie shows one section (Movies) with cells. However, I do not know how to create more than one section under a segment.

FYI, both sections and cells will not be modified or deleted by users.

I tried to find the answer online but was not really successful.

Thank you for help, guys!

**Edit:**
There are the pieces of code that I have in my project right now (names of sections and objects are different - this is just an example). There are two major problems:
1. Every segment shows just one section (of the same name). I plan to add more sections/objects later. What changes should I make in ViewController.swift to show more sections?
2. I had to repeat sections in ViewController.swift (e.g. let pulpFiction: [String] =... )to populate cells because I don't know how to access them in SectionsData.swift. I know there has to be a better way to do that - please, can you advise?

**Section.swift**

```
struct Section {
    var heading : String
    var items : [String]

    init(title: String, objects : [String]) {

        heading = title
        items = objects
    }
}
```

**SectionsData.swift**

```
var segment1Count: Int!
var segment2Count: Int!
var segment3Count: Int!

let section1 = Section(title: "Pulp Fiction", objects: ["John Travolta", "Quentin Tarantino", "Uma Thurman", "Samuel L. Jackson"])
let section2 = Section(title: "12 Angry Men", objects: ["Henry Fonda", "Lee J. Cobb", "Martin Balsam", "John Fiedler"])
let section3 = Section(title: "Fight Club", objects: ["Edward Norton", "Brad Pitt"])


class SectionsData {

    func getSectionsFromData() -> [Section] {

        var sectionsArray = [Section]()

        sectionsArray.append(section1)
        sectionsArray.append(section2)
        sectionsArray.append(section3)

        segment1Count = section1.items.count
        segment2Count = section2.items.count
        segment3Count = section3.items.count

        return sectionsArray
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
var sections: [Section] = SectionsData().getSectionsFromData()

let pulpFiction: [String] = ["John Travolta", "Quentin Tarantino", "Uma Thurman", "Samuel L. Jackson"]
let angryMen: [String] = ["Henry Fonda", "Lee J. Cobb", "Martin Balsam", "John Fiedler"]
let fightClub:  [String] = ["Edward Norton", "Brad Pitt"]

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        var sectionsNumber = 0

        switch(segmentedControlOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex) {

        case 0:
            sectionsNumber = sections.count
            break

        case 1:
            sectionsNumber = 1
            break

        case 2:
            sectionsNumber = 1
            break

        case 3:
            sectionsNumber = 1
            break

        default:
            break
        }

        return sectionsNumber
    }


internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var numberOfRows: Int!

    switch(segmentedControlOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:
        numberOfRows = sections[section].items.count
        break

    case 1:
        numberOfRows = segment1Count
        break

    case 2:
        numberOfRows = segment2Count
        break

    case 3:
        numberOfRows = segment3Count
        break

    default:
        break
    }

    return numberOfRows
}


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        var sectionHeader: String!

        switch(segmentedControlOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex) {

        case 0:
            sectionHeader = sections[section].heading
            break

        case 1:
            sectionHeader = segmentedControlOutlet.titleForSegmentAtIndex(1)
            break

        case 2:
            sectionHeader = segmentedControlOutlet.titleForSegmentAtIndex(2)
            break

        case 3:
            sectionHeader = segmentedControlOutlet.titleForSegmentAtIndex(3)
            break

        default:
            break
        }

        return sectionHeader
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("prototypeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    switch(segmentedControlOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:
        cell.textLabel!.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
        break
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel!.text = pulpFiction[indexPath.row]
        break

    case 2:
        cell.textLabel!.text = angryMen[indexPath.row]
        break

    case 3:
        cell.textLabel!.text = fightClub[indexPath.row]
        break

    default:
        break
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Actually you need a model `Movie` (a custom struct or class) which contains at least a property `title` and an array `actors`. Your data source array contains the movies as the sections, the title of the section is `title` of the movies and the rows in each section are the `actors` arrays respectively.

Comment: I have just updated pieces of my code. Please can you check it and let me know how to implement changes to achieve what I described in the first post? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple example based on your `Section` struct:

The example affects only the `ViewController` class and the `UISegmentedControl` instance is supposed to have two sections: `Movies`(index 0) and `Music` (index 1)

- For convenience declare an enum for the section indices

  ```
  enum SectionIndex : Int {
    case Movies, Music
  }
  ```
- Declare the data source array

  ```
  var sections = [Section]()
  ```
- Create a method to populate the `sections` array depending on an index

  ```
    func updateSections(index : SectionIndex)
    {
      sections.removeAll()
      switch index {
      case .Movies:
        sections.append(Section(title: "Pulp Fiction", objects: ["John Travolta", "Quentin Tarantino", "Uma Thurman", "Samuel L. Jackson"]))
        sections.append(Section(title: "12 Angry Men", objects: ["Henry Fonda", "Lee J. Cobb", "Martin Balsam", "John Fiedler"]))
        sections.append(Section(title: "Fight Club", objects: ["Edward Norton", "Brad Pitt"]))
      case .Music:
        sections.append(Section(title: "The Beatles", objects: ["John Lennon", "Paul McCartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr"]))
        sections.append(Section(title: "Genesis", objects: ["Phil Collins", "Mike Rutherford", "Tony Banks"]))
        sections.append(Section(title: "Queen", objects: ["Freddie Mercury", "Brian May", "Roger Taylor", "John Deacon"]))
      }
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` call `updateSections` with the default index.

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateSections(.Movies)
  }
  ```
- Connect the action `valueChanged` of the segmented control to this `IBAction`

  ```
  @IBAction func didChangeValue(control : UISegmentedControl)
  {
    updateSections(SectionIndex(rawValue:control.selectedSegmentIndex)!)
  }
  ```
- These are the table view data source and delegate methods

  ```
  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let section = sections[section]
    return section.items.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("prototypeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  
    let section = sections[indexPath.section]
    cell.textLabel!.text = section.items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section].heading
  }
  ```

Now when you tap on the segmented control the `sections` array is updated accordingly and the table view is reloaded. However using `Core Data` and `NSFetchedResultController` would be still more efficient. You have just to change the fetch request and re-fetch the data.

Comment: It seems to be working fine, thank you so much! One more question - what would be the best way to populate All segment (except copy-pasting all sections.append...)? Thanks again.

Comment: If it's a kind of an immutable data base, maybe a property list file, but I'd prefer Core Data.